# remove NA's with complete.cases, undefined columns error despite use of comma

Tags: r, na

It has been asked a couple of times on the Internet and every time I read the same answers; but it still doesn't work with me. I don't know what I do wrong.
I want to remove all rows that have one or more NA in it, from my file called "joined_file".

```
joined_file[complete.cases(joined_file), ]
```

Why does this still return "undefined columns selected"? 
As far as I can see, the NA values are not strings because there are no "". 
(this is an example of an NA row)

```
  word auditory gustatory haptic olfactory visual concreteness freq_by_million
NA <NA>       NA        NA     NA        NA     NA           NA              NA
   dominant_position
NA              <NA>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data or data frame as a reproducible example? [mre]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `joined_file` looks like? Is it currently an object in your environment? Is it a `data.frame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest and easiest method to remove rows with `NA`is via `na.omit`:

```
na.omit(df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
2    C    A    B    C    A
3    A    B    B    B    A
4    C    B    C    C    A
9    B    A    A    A    A
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = T),
  col2 = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = T),
  col3 = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = T),
  col4 = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = T),
  col5 = sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:3]), 10, replace = T))

df
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1     A    C    C    C <NA>
2     C    A    B    C    A
3     A    B    B    B    A
4     C    B    C    C    A
5     C <NA>    B <NA> <NA>
6  <NA>    C    B    A <NA>
7     B <NA>    B    C <NA>
8     C <NA>    B <NA>    A
9     B    A    A    A    A
10    A    C <NA> <NA>    C
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!! I will share example DF in the future!

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption and Note:** The below should work, if you have data frame. Also, always provide sample data using `dput(head(your_data_frame))` as said by few others so that one can help you quickly.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
df <- tribble(~col1, ~col2, ~col3,
              NA,1,NA,
              2,3,5,
              NA,NA,NA)
df %>% drop_na()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2     3     5

df %>% drop_na(col2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA     1    NA
#> 2     2     3     5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>